# How to Sync Amazon S3 Bucket with Akamai NetStorage using python and lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, akamai

I want to automate the whole process, whenever a new image or video file comes into my s3 bucket I want to move those files to akamai netstorage using lambda and python boto or whatever best possible way.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a lambda based on s3 notifications (including file creation or deletion).

See aws walkthrough: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

Comment: hi mlavoie thanks for the reply i am aware about how to use lambda but i am concerned about the python script i need to attach with lambda function so that when triggered the data should get copy in net storage

Comment: Your question is too broad and lacks detail. Do some research, then update your question with what you have tried then ask specific questions. This is not a free code writing service, your unlikey to get a good answer from such a vague question.

Comment: My guess is that he is trying to push a from an S3 bucket to Akamai Netstorage. And wants help figuring out means to do it.  @shahebazsayed  Akamai NS supports FTP, HTTP over CMS API, SSH/SFTP/Aspera with key based login. Hope that helps. But I am not sure how to use that in Lambda

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the lambda function can be automatically executed as your file is dropped into the s3 bucket - there is a boto3 template and a trigger configurable at the lambda creation. You can further access the content from s3 bucket and propagate it to Akamai Netstorage, using this API: https://pypi.org/project/anesto/